# php no error but blank output page

Tags: php, html

this is my php code i am trying to get out put on same page but now out put is beng shown and there is no error is being shown also. can you help me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buXhx.jpg)

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="try.php" method="POST"> 
<input type="text" name="txtname"> 
<input type="text" name="txtage"> 
<input type="submit" value="send" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['txtname']) && isset($_POST['txtage'])){
$text=$_POST['txtname'];
$age=$_POST['txtage']; 
echo $text; 
echo $age; 
}
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where it has been asked ?

Comment: don't go making changes to your original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34581037/1 without stating that there was an edit / code change that you tried. The person who answered may get downvoted because of it, where people will tell/ask themselves: *"He's got them like that, so why the answer?"*. You MUST always mark code that you tried/changed underneath your original question/code and stating that that was what you tried. Besides, you still missed some and is why your code is still failing.

Comment: Oh and a blank page, usually means syntax errors, which you have. So, when learning PHP, check for those. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php which you're not and should. And is the grounds on which your question was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I also performed a rollback to your original question/code http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34581037/1, since you did not state your *Stealth edit* http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34581037/2 as being what you changed given from an answer given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `$_POST` and not `$_post`. `$_POST` is one of PHP's superglobals and must be in all caps. `$_post` will be treated as a local variable. ([ref](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php))

Comment: can you elaborate on that? There's a ***specific*** reason as to *why* it should be. Edit: yep, that's it ;-)

Comment: nothing happend same blank out put page with $_POST @patric lee

Comment: Yes, I should have elaborated on that. Just expanded the answer. @router: Did you change all four uses of `$_post` to `$_POST`? Also, is this the content of `try.php` where the form is being posted?

Comment: $_POST is a super global variable of php containa form input in an array.. if u use $_post it seems to be simple variable but I think thia variable is undefined

Comment: i have attached photo also , yes i changed it to $_POST and form is being posted on same try page its single page coding

Comment: Than chk print_r($_POST); WHAT U GETTING @router

Comment: @devpro what will be the solution then

Comment: @router: We're not sure about the solution yet. @devpro is suggesting `print_r($_POST)` in order to gather more information about the problem.

Comment: Ist of all chk what r u getting... use print_r($_POST); U WILL GET THE IDEA

Comment: echo or print are showing nothing i get blank output page with no error

Comment: Look at their edit http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34581037/revisions and look at [my comment to them...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581037/php-no-error-but-blank-output-page#comment56907326_34581037)

Comment: Based on your edited code, you still have two uses of `$_post` that need to be changed to `$_POST`.

Comment: WHY DON YOU try it on your local host

Comment: @router *"its a simple program and you expert are unable to get it ...... OMG"* - actually, yes we are.

Comment: *"WHY DON YOU try it on your local host – router"* - No need to, we already know why your code is *still* failing. @router

Comment: And insulting the people who are trying to help you is not the best move. As previously stated, make sure every use of `$_post` is changed to `$_POST`.

Comment: @fred-ii love u man.... :)

Comment: thanks @PatrickLee i have done with it you are genius

Comment: @devpro *Blowing on fingers* - heh ;-)

Comment: @router: we all told u to chk duplicate link. And if u cant than try this........    if(count($_POST) > 0){print_r($_POST); exit;}    try it and share the result...

Comment: @router: Not sure about the genius part, but glad it's working. In the future, please read answers and comments carefully and make sure you follow the suggestions to the letter.

Comment: its done. it was error of $POST instead of $post @PatrickLee was right